# Ripple voltage on output voltage of an smps

Tags: capacitor, switch-mode-power-supply, flyback

I am trying to select the output capacitors of a flyback topology (without using a second LC filter). This is a general question. My question is how evolved the ripple voltage in function of the different capacitor parameters. Apparently, it depends on the capacitance itself, but above all it depends on the ESR value of the capacitor. It seems that the number of capacitors would help for having the required ripple voltage.

Here are the following AN that I read :
https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/application_note/09/94/ed/b6/59/57/43/9b/CD00004190.pdf/files/CD00004190.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00004190.pdf

https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slva559/slva559.pdf

https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/AN-4137.pdf.pdf

In the first document :

[image]

It misses some informations to me, it is said that if the output capacitor is sufficiently large we can consider that only the ESR would be a problem for the voltage ripple... Nevertheless where does this relation come from ? I would like to know this relation which allows to tell this assertion.

Some of the answer could be in the third document :

[image]

Where Vro is the reflected output voltage at the primary of the n-th output
Where Kl(n) is defined as follows :

[image]

And Idspeak is the primary peak current.

I do not understand the formula. If I took a look on it :

[image]

The part encircled in red is equal to the turn ratio. Then multiplied by the Idspeak which is equal to the primary peak current, it gives us the secondary peak current. Finally we can consider that the secondary peak current is equal to Iout plus the capacitor current. We get :

$$
\mathrm{
DeltaV_{o(n)} = \frac{I_{o(n)}*D_{max}}{C_{o(n)}*f_{s}} + (I_{o(n)}+I_{cap(n)})*R_{c(n)}*K_{L(n)} 
}
$$

I some troubles to understand this relation...

Here is the relation that I founded according to my calculs it may be false ... And I think I have done some approximations that are debatable. Please bring me to light.

I have considered that the ripple voltage is sufficiently low as to consider the output voltage constant and then if Pout is constant, then the load draw a constant current. I considered the circuit at the primary MOSFET OFF time.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzjw9B.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Then :

$$
\mathrm{
V_{min} = -R_{esr}*I_{out} + (V_{C(avg)} - deltaV_{C(OFF)})
}
$$

$$
\mathrm{
V_{min} = -R_{esr}*I_{out} + (V_{C(avg)} - \frac{I_{out}*(1-D_{max})}{C_{out}*F_{sw}})
}
$$

Then I considered that the average capacitor voltage is equal to the average output voltage. I think it is true, but mathematically this is not clear ... So we get :

$$
\mathrm{
V_{min} = -R_{esr}*I_{out} + (V_{out} - \frac{I_{out}*(1-D_{max})}{C_{out}*F_{sw}})
}
$$

$$
\mathrm{
V_{out}-V_{min} = R_{esr}*I_{out} + \frac{I_{out}*(1-D_{max})}{C_{out}*F_{sw}})
}
$$

which is equal to :

$$
\mathrm{
\frac{deltaV_{out}}{2} = R_{esr}*I_{out} + \frac{I_{out}*(1-D_{max})}{C_{out}*F_{sw}})
}
$$

And as the first document shows, if C is large we can neglige the second term, and we see the the ripple voltage depends only on the equivalent series resistance.

Do you think my formula is correct ?

I would like to plot a graphic where we see the output voltage ripple in function of the ESR and the capacitance value (I could do a 3D plot if necessary)

Thank you very much and have a nice day !

Comment: The ripple is made of two components, resistive and capacitive. By looking at the waveform with an oscilloscope, you can tell which one dominates. In a highly pulsating output current converter like a flyback converter, you select the output capacitor based on the circulating rms current. Then, from the available normalized value, you have a certain ESR and you check the ripple from this component is within your specs. If not, you parallel more caps. You can of course evaluate the capacitor using formulas, but rms current and ESR usually rule at the end.

Comment: Thank you @VerbalKint, I would like to evaluate without doing any experiments the influence of the capacitor value and the ESR value on the ripple voltage. Do you think my formula is correct ? I would like to plot a 3D plot with Z = Ripple voltage ; X = ESR value and Y = capacitor value. For the moment, I will not consider the rms current circulating into the capacitors for simplicity.

Comment: I could try do a simulation on LTspice to see if my formula correspond to the simulation.

Comment: Actually I do not want to put many capacitors and take place on my board just for an ESR problem. If I need to reduce the ESR, I prefer to buy a better capacitor with a lower ESR